# call operator on a tree node in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm writing a collapsable tree with d3 in which I want to add and to remove nodes. Starting from the example from d3 website (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) I've added two symbols for adding/removing nodes beside every node and I used the call() function for calling an add_node() or the remove_node() function.

The relevant code is:

```
function update(source) {

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 80;
    });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function (d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dy", "4px")
    .attr("font-size", 0)
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.value;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 0.1);


    // X sign and circle for clicking on it
    // ...
    node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", radius *0.8)
    .attr("cx", -radius*1.5)
    .attr("cy", "0px")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .call(remove_node);

    // plus sign and circle for clicking on it
    // ...
    node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", radius)
    .attr("cx", radius * 1.5)
    .attr("cy", "0px")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .call(add_node);

    // ...
}

function add_node(node) {
    console.log("add node")
}


function remove_node(node) {
   console.log("remove node");
}
```

The problem is that whether I click the node, the add symbol or the remove symbol, the result is always that the node is expanded or collapsed (depending on the starting state) and both the add_node() and remove_node() functions are called, as if the three calls are hooked to the same event, while what I'd like to have is that clicking on the node makes the node expand/collapse, and clicking on the add symbol calls only the add_node() function, and clicking on the remove symbol calls only the remove_node() function.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andreaiacono/yd5r6u4t/1/

Any hint on where I'm wrong?

Thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've added the node, it's text the add symbol components and the remove symbol components under and single g element. Group them into 3 sub-groups instead.

Then change your `.call` to a `.on('click'...`. Thus this

> ```
> // plus sign and circle for clicking on it
> node.append("line")
> .attr("stroke", "#AAA")
> .attr("stroke-width", "2")
> .attr("x1", radius * 1.2)
> .attr("y1", "0px")
> .attr("x2", radius * 1.8)
> .attr("y2", "0px")
>
> node.append("line")
> .attr("stroke", "#AAA")
> .attr("stroke-width", "2")
> .attr("x1", radius * 1.5)
> .attr("y1", -radius * 0.3)
> .attr("x2", radius * 1.5)
> .attr("y2", radius * 0.3)
>
> node.append("circle")
> .attr("r", radius)
> .attr("cx", radius * 1.5)
> .attr("cy", "0px")
> .style("fill-opacity", 0)
> .style("opacity", 0)
> .call(add_node);
> ```

would become

```
// plus sign group
var gan = node.append("g")
    .on('click', add_node);

gan.append("line")
    .attr("stroke", "#AAA")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2")
    .attr("x1", radius * 1.2)
    .attr("y1", "0px")
    .attr("x2", radius * 1.8)
    .attr("y2", "0px")

gan.append("line")
    .attr("stroke", "#AAA")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2")
    .attr("x1", radius * 1.5)
    .attr("y1", -radius * 0.3)
    .attr("x2", radius * 1.5)
    .attr("y2", radius * 0.3)
```

Similarly for the other 2 sets of components (I see you already have part of it for the node expand / collapse)

By the way, you can add back the circles for the x and + if you need more click area.

---

Updated Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6egecqzt/